# MySQL sorting according to 2 records

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this table and records:

```
Table: advertiser

id  |   company_id   |   start_date   |   end_date
----+----------------+----------------+-------------
  1 |   2            |  2016-08-01    |  2016-10-12
  2 |   3            |  2016-09-14    |  2016-12-01
  3 |   2            |  2016-10-15    |  2017-02-10
```

I want to select records `group by company_id` from this table sorting by `start_date` but because I grouped by `company_id` I can just select id:3 so in sorting this record show at end of list.

this is my query:

```
SELECT id
FROM advertiser
WHERE end_date >= NOW()
GROUP BY company_id
ORDER BY start_date ASC
```

and selected records ids will be :

```
first: 2
second: 3
```

How can I select records like this ?

```
first: 3
second: 2
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to add `where` to my query.

Comment: Why `3` would be first? `2` has an the early and the last`start_date`

Comment: `... ORDER BY MAX(start_date) DESC`

Comment: In your query why your do `SELECT id` instead of `SELECT company_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/OTRT65710)**

```
SELECT `id`, cia_last.`company_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, mdate
FROM (
        SELECT `id`, `company_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`,
                @rn := if(@company_id = `company_id`,
                          @rn + 1,
                          if(@company_id := `company_id`,1,1)
                         ) as rn                       
        FROM advertiser
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @company_id := '', @rn := 0) as par
        ORDER BY `company_id`, `start_date` desc
     ) cia_last
INNER JOIN ( SELECT  `company_id`, MIN(`start_date`) as mdate
             FROM advertiser
             GROUP BY `company_id`) cia_first
   ON cia_last.`company_id` = cia_first.`company_id`
WHERE rn = 1   
ORDER BY mdate
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm so sorry, I forgotten to add where to my query, I updated my question.

Comment: Then your query should be ok. The first row will be `3` and not `2` as you show

Comment: this query return 2 records because NOW is bigger than 2016-10-12, and now I want order by start_date of id:1 (which not in selected records), is it possible ?

Comment: Again your query, already solve that, just `order by` would do it, or `order by MIN(start_date)`

Comment: Unless you are working with a bigger sample? and you arent getting the right result?

Comment: for this 2 records may be work, but in more than these 2 records I have problem, you can test it if you have more than 2 records.

Comment: Again, read my comment. You need to explain what result you want. you can update this [**demo**](http://rextester.com/CBVX18020) with more data. And update your question showing the problem.

Comment: Please visit this sample: http://rextester.com/TJSW35852 , this show : 2,4,3,5,6 but I want to show: 3,2,4,5,6 (because `start_date` of record with id 1 is `2016-08-01` and `company_id` of 1 & 3 is 2

Comment: Again why you `SELECT id` instead of `SELECT company_id` ? company_id give you that result `3,4,2,5,6`

Comment: If I can understand your mean correctly, I need id of records in this table, because I should use `id` for show in table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128486/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-majafy).